# Header file with a struct and function prototypes using the keyword "extern"

Tags: c, function, struct, prototype

I'm trying to define a struct in a header file with function prototypes that take pointer to that struct as a parameter.

```
#ifndef _GETDATA
#define _GETDATA
struct PERSONDATA{
    char name[20];
    double age,mass;
};
typedef struct PERSONDATA person;
extern void getData(person *);
extern void getName(char *,int);
#endif
```

The getData.c file is defined as such;

```
#include <stdio.h>
void getData(person *ptr)
{
    printf("Enter name: ");
    getName(ptr->name,sizeof(ptr->name));
}
```

and the getName.c file is defined as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void getName(char *ptrName, int varSize)
{
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        *(ptrName++) = getchar();
        ++i;
        if(i==varSize) printf("array full, EXITING!\n");
    }while(*(ptrName-1)!='\n' && i<varSize);
}
```

Lastly, the main function was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GETDATA.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    person human1;
    printf("hello, world!\n\n");
    getData(&human1);
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling the program, I get the following error:

```
***C:/Users/Shoaib.Shoaib-PC/Google Drive/C workspace/C workspace codelite/StructPointerExample/getData.c:2:14: error: unknown type name 'person',
void getData(person *ptr)***
```

Could some one please help me out here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `getData.c` needs to include the header (`GETDATA.h`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the header file in ALL files using the declared types, not just in the main file.